# How to plot a background in a Pine Script indicator only the first time the condition is met?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've managed to create an indicator which measures the price change (%) of a selected asset from a user specified hour of the day every day. I've also included a background color change of the indicator whenever the price change reaches a user specified level (only positive numbers for now). However, I'd like to change the background color only the first time the specified price change level is reached in a day. What would you suggest?

Thank you.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = 'Price Change (%) From a Specific Time of the Day', shorttitle = 'PC (%)', overlay = false)

input_hour = input.int(title = 'Hour', minval = 0, maxval = 23, defval = 23, tooltip = 'Selected time is in the timezone of the exchange.')
input_minute = input.int(title = 'Minute', minval = 0, maxval = 59, defval = 0)
input_percentage = input.int(title = 'Price Change (%) Signal Level', minval = 0, maxval = 1000, defval = 5)

var initial_time = 0.0
initial_time := hour == input_hour and minute == input_minute ? close : initial_time
price_change_percentage = math.round((close - initial_time) / initial_time * 100 * 100) / 100
price_change_percentage_crossover = ta.crossover(price_change_percentage, input_percentage)

price_change_line_color = price_change_percentage > 0 ? color.new(#089981, 0) : price_change_percentage < 0 ? color.new(#f23645, 0) : na
plot(price_change_percentage, title = 'Price Change (%) Color', color = price_change_line_color, linewidth = 1)
hline(price = 0, title = 'Zero Line', color = color.new(color.white, 70))
bgcolor(hour == input_hour and minute == input_minute ? color.new(color.white, 80) : na, title = "Selected Time Background")
bgcolor(price_change_percentage_crossover == true ? color.new(color.green, 50) : na, title = "Price Change Cross Background")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what you are asking by creating a boolean that turns true once the price change crossover has occurred and then resets every new day.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = 'Price Change (%) From a Specific Time of the Day', shorttitle = 'PC (%)', overlay = false)

input_hour = input.int(title = 'Hour', minval = 0, maxval = 23, defval = 23, tooltip = 'Selected time is in the timezone of the exchange.')
input_minute = input.int(title = 'Minute', minval = 0, maxval = 59, defval = 0)
input_percentage = input.int(title = 'Price Change (%) Signal Level', minval = 0, maxval = 1000, defval = 5)

var priceChangeReached = false
var initial_time = 0.0

newDay = ta.change(time('D'))
initial_time := hour == input_hour and minute == input_minute ? close : initial_time
price_change_percentage = math.round((close - initial_time) / initial_time * 100 * 100) / 100
price_change_percentage_crossover = ta.crossover(price_change_percentage, input_percentage)

if price_change_percentage_crossover
    priceChangeReached := true

price_change_line_color = price_change_percentage > 0 ? color.new(#089981, 0) : price_change_percentage < 0 ? color.new(#f23645, 0) : na
plot(price_change_percentage, title = 'Price Change (%) Color', color = price_change_line_color, linewidth = 1)
hline(price = 0, title = 'Zero Line', color = color.new(color.white, 70))
bgcolor(hour == input_hour and minute == input_minute ? color.new(color.white, 80) : na, title = "Selected Time Background")
bgcolor(price_change_percentage_crossover and priceChangeReached[1] == false ?  color.new(color.green, 50) : na, title = "Price Change Cross Background")

if newDay
    priceChangeReached := false
```